# New AWS Lambda URLs - has anyone got the 'secure' version with the AWS_IAM working?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a simple function that returns an item of text.

When I set auth to NONE it works fine.

When I set auth to AWS_IAM and create the resource based policy within the permissions section of AWS Lambda I set the following:

```
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "default",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "sid8",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxx:user/xxxxxxxxxx"
      },
      "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunctionUrl",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-1:xxxxxxxxx:function:simpleFunction",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "lambda:FunctionUrlAuthType": "AWS_IAM"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

On this I get a forbidden error.

Every demo / example on the internet uses NONE for auth.

I have also tried adding the `lambda:InvokeFunctionUrl` to the IAM policy of the user for the specified resource but still getting a forbidden error.

Am I missing something or does this aspect of the new function not work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that when you are using `IAM_AUTH` you're required to sign your requests with `SigV4`. Essentially, this is identical to using API Gateway with IAM_AUTH type.

There are multiple ways of signing requests  you can even use `botocore` functionality to do so. The easiest would be to use [awscurl](https://github.com/okigan/awscurl) or [postman](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/iam-authentication-api-gateway/), also check this doco that confirms this requirement https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/urls-invocation.html